# PostgreSQL: COPY FROM SQL to specific columns

Tags: python, postgresql, filepath, psycopg2, string-substitution

I have been trying to figure out how to format a `COPY FROM` SQL statement for most of the morning and I need help.

I am trying to import data from an ASCII text file to a table in my Postgres database. I am thinking it does not like how I am specifying the input ASCII file. I have tried both of the file paths with no luck:

```
file = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('c:\\','Users','dan','Desktop','New_Folder','Sept_2014','R01761','R01761_tex.asc'))
file = r'C:\Users\dan\Desktop\New_folder\Sept_2014\R01761\R01761_tex.asc'
```

Here is my script I am using to access my database:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='reach_4a' user='root' host='localhost' port='9000' password='myPassword'")
    tblname = "sept_2014""
    file = r"C:\Users\dan\Desktop\New_folder\Sept_2014\R01761\R01761_tex.asc"
    #file = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('c:\\','Users','dan','Desktop','New_Folder','Sept_2014','R01761','R01761_tex.asc'))
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "COPY %s (easting,northing,texture) FROM %s DELIMITERS ' ';" % (tblname,file) 
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

#Close Database
try:
    conn.close()
    print 'Database connection destroyed'
except:
    print "I cant close the database"
```

When I step through my script in a python console, I get the following error when i try and run the `cur.execute(sql)` line:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-c26e11f8fb81> in <module>()
----> 1 cur.execute(sql)

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "c"
LINE 1: COPY sept_2014 (easting,northing,texture) FROM c:\Users\dan\...
                                                       ^
```

Am I properly substituting my strings to my SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *put the path into quotes*:

```
"COPY %s (easting,northing,texture) FROM '%s' DELIMITERS ' ';"
```

---

I would also think about parameterizing the query with the file path:

```
sql = "COPY {field} (easting,northing,texture) FROM %s DELIMITERS ' ';".format(field=tblname)
cur.execute(sql, (file, ))
```

Note that in this case the database driver would be responsible for putting quotes around a string value. And, as a bonus, you are now preventing [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Note that we have to insert the field into the query via the string formatting. Make sure you know where `tblname` is coming from and you either trust the source, or validate/escape/sanitize it before using in the query.

Comment: When I try to implement the parameterizing the query with the file path method I get the following error: `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not open file "C:\Users\dan\Desktop\New_folder\Sept_2014\R01761\R01761_tex.asc" for reading: No such file or directory`.  But `os.path.isfile(file)` returns true.

Comment: @dubbbdan well, are you getting the same error if you just put the quotes around the placeholder (the first suggestion in the answer)? Thanks.

Comment: @dubbbdan okay, at least it is not related to the answer and a follow-up problem. What if you check it with `os.path.exists(file)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102642/discussion-between-dubbbdan-and-alecxe).